# InApp Purchase - Expiration and Start Date details

Tags: android, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I have implemented the InApp purchase in android for first time using

```
Android In-App Billing v3 Library
```

The subscription are successfully charged and displaying subscribed on Playstore, but not able to get the subscription expiry date and other information. The info am getting from respose is

```
**{
    "orderId": "GPA.3338-1902-5576-33309",
    "packageName": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "productId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "purchaseTime": 1568890677033,
    "purchaseState": 0,
    "developerPayload": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "purchaseToken": "nablcikpknhkbfdkekhghiii.AO-J1OzE4eRePSXFnfV3ME-Gf50pkU6PzbSU3PKOmkR3Iwag040piJGUng9MLdUSylWRf1X8Mw5HlTMw_diU3_2Ez7-gja68tZm9iNkIu7A3IQfIqFmrthiXktwd_zlpukAhqSu9K5w6",
    "autoRenewing": true
}
```

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620506/how-to-get-subscription-expire-date-in-inapp-v3-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get subscription expire date in inapp v3 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620506/how-to-get-subscription-expire-date-in-inapp-v3-android)

Comment: Not able to find billingService interface in above library

Answer (score 0):

Why would you worry about the subscription expiration date? Every time upon your app launches, you should call queryPurchases API from Play Billing Library.

This API will return a list of active SKUs (in-app and subs). If the subscription has expired, it won't be returned by this API. With that, you know the users is no long subscribed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I got exipre date